# How to match sequences of consecutive Money like characters string in Dart?

Tags: regex, dart

I have sequences of consecutive money like characters string  like:

```
"000000000012735"
```

and I want use regex to cover sequences of consecutive Money like characters string to Money type or in Dart double like:

```
"127.35"
```

Incoming sequences of consecutive Money like characters string length is 15.

I am just trying to learn regex and I try to use:

```
final value =  "000000000012735".replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'.{13}'), (match) => "${match.group(0)} ");
 print('value: $value');
```

but it dived string and doesn't add . in empty space as:

```
value: 0000000000127 35
```

What is correct **regex pattern** to **convert** above format as I describe above in Dart?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, sorry. I update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```dart
final text = '000000000012735';
print(text.replaceFirstMapped(RegExp(r'^0*(\d+)(\d{2})$'), (Match m) => 
   "${m[1]}.${m[2]}"));
```

The output is `127.35`.

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(\d{2})` - Group 2: two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note that since one replacement is expected, there is no need using `replaceAllMapped`, `replaceFirstMapped` will do.

Comment: Thank you very much.